# I can't figure out what is wrong and I am brand new to this

Tags: python-2.7

## I'm just messing around and I can't figure out what is wrong

```
name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
hi = raw_input('Are you having a good day, %s. \n' % name

if hi == "yes"
  i == raw_input("great. \n")
  if i = "thanks":
    q = raw_input("you're welcome \n")
    if q == "bye":
      print("=)")
              
    else:
      print("Have a great day, Good Bye \n")
elif hi == "no":
        
  n = raw_input("that is sad. hope your day gets better, %s \n" % name)
  if n == "bye":
    print("Good Bye, %s \n" % name)
  else:
    print("Hope your day gets better, Good Bye.")
else:
  print(" ")
  print(" ")
  print("                   Please enter yes or no.")
  print("              *You need to restart the program")
```

it is saying invalid syntax for (  i == raw_input("great. \n")  )

Comment: `if hi == "yes":` you're just missing a `:`

Answer (score 1):

In python when you see `invalid syntax for "whatever"` check for the line above the "whatever"

so your problem is a missing `:` at the first if statement

```
if hi == "yes"
```

should be

```
if hi == "yes":
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, you're just missing a `:` after `if hi == "yes"`.

This is a common error and the message points you to the line after the actual problem.